# Continuity of a map from the 2-plane.

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow X$ be a map where $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space. Assume that the restriction of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$ is continuous, and the restriction of $f$ on any straight line $l$ passing through the origin  $0$ is continuous. Is $f$  continuous on $ \mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y) = \cases {0,&if $(x,y)=(0,0)$\\
xy^2/(x^2+y^4) &otherwise}$$

> Is $f$ continuous when restricted to an arbitrary line in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Can you prove it?
>
> Is $f$ continuous? (Try taking a path along the graph of a non-linear polynomial. What is the simplest non-linear polynomial you know?).

Comment: Thanks, get it. y=kx, x=ly, and x=y^2

Comment: Yep, have fun proving these results. It might be easier to just use $y=kx$ and $x=0$ for your lines instead of both $y=kx$ and  $x=ly$.